# How to create objects from user input - C#

Tags: c#, user-input

I'm a beginner in OOP and have recently started coding in C#. (working in Visual Studio 2017 Console application.)
After searching around for tutorials i will try my luck here.

I'm trying to make a simple program that would allow a user to make a new object book(or multiple) by asking them for input. I know how to manually create an object of the class but not how to do the same with user input. this is the code i have so far:

```
public class book
{
    //variables
    private string title;
    private string author;
    private string genre;
    private string series;

    //constructor
    public book(string _titel, string _author, string _genre, string _series)
    {
        this.titel = _titel;
        this.author = _author;
        this.genre = _genre;
        this.series = _series;
    }

    //method to ask user for input to create book
    public void createBook()
    {

    }
```

Comment: What is your input scenario? Are you using a console app? Web app?

Comment: Since your `createBook` method is part of your class, `createBook` cannot be called until *after* the `book` object is already created. If you want to allow users to create a book, you should prompt the user for everything before the object is created, and then call the `book` constructor with the inputs that the user has provided.

Comment: So what *can* you do so far? Can you ask a user for input and echo it to them? If not, it might be time to study that chapter of your book for a while.

Comment: The app asks the user for all the strings, and then you create the object and initialize it with those strings. To create a book object in code call `new book();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("Input Title: ");
var title = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Input Author: "):
var author = Console.ReadLine();
etc..
var book = new Book(title,author etc...)
```

You get the inputs as variable and then construct your object from those variables.

Answer (score 0):

createBook() shouldn't be in the book class. Theoretically, creating your book is what your constructor should be doing. You need to put createBook() somewhere it can call the constructor and have the book exist (and change void to a book object).

but if you keep it void in main (or wherever you want it), you'd want to call

```
createBook(); // although you can't do much with it as it returns a void
```

and have your function defined as

```
void createBook(){
    // get input for _titel, _author, _genre, _series
    Book = book(_titel, _author, _genre, _series);
    console.writeline("book created! such a shame all its a properties are private, because I'd really like to output the title or something.")
}
```

Comment: So would you instead make another class called user which would have a method in it to get the details of a book? for instance : public string getBookDetails() which would then ask for the user input titel , author etc and return those?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely one way to do it.